# Got NSCocoaErrorDomain code=261 when reading xml file

Tags: ios, xml, encoding, bundle

I am trying to read a COLLADA file (xml formatted, utf-8 encoding) with following code:

```
NSString *xmlPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"astroBoy_walk_Max" ofType:@"dae"];
NSError *error;
NSString *xmlContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:xmlPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

The returned xmlContent is nil and error @"NSCocoaErrorDomain" - code: 261.

Then I tried with other encoding like `NSASCIIStringEncoding` and the xmlContent is not nil but contained string `"bplist00Ô\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\a\bZzippedData_\x10\x1creaderMinimumRequiredVersionVzippedWversionO\x12..."` which obviously not original file content.

And later I renamed the file's extension to `dat`, and read with almost the same code:

```
NSString *xmlPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"astroBoy_walk_Max" ofType:@"dat"];
NSError *error;
NSString *xmlContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:xmlPath encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
```

Everything looks good, the xmlContent contains correct file content string...

What is the problem when I reading the raw .dae file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The collada files are compressed on compilation time

> When you include a scene file in Collada or Alembic format in your
>   Xcode project, Xcode automatically converts the file to SceneKit’s
>   compressed scene format for use in the built app. The compressed file
>   retains its original .dae or .abc extension.

from [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNSceneSource_Class/)

If you open the app bundle and read the collada file as text you'll realize it's different from the one you added to your project